# What's the meaning of 'path/to/the/cache/dir'?

Tags: php

I want to use [phpbrowscap](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/wiki/QuickStart) in my php project in wamp.

To create a new object of this class I use this code:

```
    / phpbrowscap follows the PSR-0 standard, so just require the composer autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// The Browscap class is in the phpbrowscap namespace, so import it
use phpbrowscap\Browscap;

// Create a new Browscap object (loads or creates the cache)
$bc = new Browscap('path/to/the/cache/dir');

// Get information about the current browser's user agent
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();
```

But I don't understand where the cache directory ('path/to/the/cache/dir') to replace it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the cache directory yourself using `mkdir cache` in your project's root directory. Then just make sure that the directory is owned by the proper user/group (**www-data** by default in Apache) using:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data cache
```

and make sure that the cache directory has its permissions set up to allow read/write access for that user using:

```
sudo chmod 644 cache
```